# Shut down Android TV

Tags: remote-control, android-tv, power-options

I have a Philips 58PUS8505/62 4K LED Android TV. Normally, I want to power off the TV by switching off the power outlet the TV is connected. However, the TV or its remote does not provide a menu or key combination (that I know of) to shut down the operating system and power off the TV *before I cut the power*.

When I press the red (power) button on the remote, the TV goes into standby. However Android continues to run and I see disk IO on the external disk connected to the USB port of the TV. I know how to "unmount" the external disk, but my question is not on this.

I tried to **long press** the power button on the remote (external TV boxes work this way), but nothing different happens.

There seems to be no way to power off the TV. What am I missing?

Comment: Apparently, to power off the TV completely the user manual for your TV recommends the way you already know of. *To switch off the TV completely, disconnect the power plug.* -- user manual, page 11 at https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/5/58pus8505_12/58pus8505_12_dfu_eng.pdf#page=11

Comment: Yes. But this is exactly the same as removing the battery of your phone without shutting down Android, unplugging your desktop computer without shutting down Windows / Linux, or turning down the power of a system room's cabinet without orderly shutting down your servers and storage systems in it!

Comment: That's exactly what I am searching the answer for, right now.

Comment: How would you power on with remote if in android everything is an app?

Comment: If you have the ability to install android root apps, create a widget that executes "svc power shutdown" or "reboot -p" (the latter one just kills the android session afaik)

Comment: Thanks for the info @alecxs , but I am not going to root the system. :(

Comment: This reddit post suggests there might be settings that control this power "feature" either found at `Settings > Power > Eco` or `Settings > About`: https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidTV/comments/93x3xz/how_to_fully_shutdown_android_tv/

Comment: [Turn off using Google Assistant may work](https://www.nextpit.com/hot-to-use-google-assistant-to-watch-tv) // I don't have any TV, so can't test

Comment: there are plenty of shutdown apps in google play. needs accessibility permissions

Comment: [`Termux and Fakeroot`](https://www.crisisshelter.org/get-root-access-in-termux-without-root-fakeroot/)  That will let you poweroff. Then create a script and run it after testing the command. This is a `rootless` solution. If this does not work - vist the nearest Goodwill store  & be generious and get another one that gives you the  freedom. Plernty of CC Cheap China Boxes .